# Failed getting cipher list warning on Tomcat 8.0.53 startup

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, apr

I'm getting `Failed getting cipher list` warning in catalina log on a Tomcat start after adding tomcat native library. I used `bin/tomcat-native.tar.gz` sources to build lib with the following config:

- OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips
- APR 1.4.8
- JDK 1.8.0_191-b12

What could cause such warning?
Here's the stacktrace:

```
26-Dec-2018 07:34:41.234 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.<clinit> Failed getting cipher list
 java.lang.Exception: Invalid Server SSL Protocol (error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0))
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSLContext.make(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.<clinit>(OpenSSLEngine.java:73)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getImplementedProtocols(OpenSSLUtil.java:63)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:67)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.<init>(OpenSSLUtil.java:42)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation.getSSLUtil(OpenSSLImplementation.java:36)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:86)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1087)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:265)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:661)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

Comment: Please post your `<Connector>` configuration and also the part of the log that contains all the version numbers detected by `libtcnative`. Also, Tomcat 8.0 has reached [end-of-life](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html).

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, thanks for being interested here! I was able to resolve the issue after I used OpenSSL 1.1.0j.